# how to get the last 30 entries of an array?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I get the last 30 entries of my array? I have no clue how to define the lenght of the array and then take out the last entries only. This is the script:

```
function gTrend(term) {
  var resp=[];
  var url="https://apitrendscript-666.ey.r.appspot.com/interestOverTime?keyword="+term;
  var body=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var data=JSON.parse(body);
  var timelineData=data["default"].timelineData;

  
  for (var i in timelineData) {
    var tdata=timelineData[i];
    resp.push(tdata.value[0]);
  }
  return resp;
}

function testGTrends(){
  gTrend("mobfish");
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this link.  Use -30 from the end.  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Comment: Array.slice(-30);

Comment: that did the trick, thanks!